# Setting Relationships on Pre-existingData is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I want to use relationships in core-data on data that already has been imported.

In other words the data gets imported from a mysql import...

Then I want to use relationships in core-data to connect entities via my own pre-existing data .

Is this even possible????

Comment: The answer below is exactly what I said in my answers to your other 2 questions. Please stop asking the same question all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but in this case you must write your own functions for get data from your relationship, in Core Data. I'm think this very bad way to use Core Data. Much better is manually set all relationships, when you import data from sqlite DB.